# ASP.NET cannot sent email from smtp

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, gmail

[back to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834750/asp-net-smtp-gmail-failed). I am still have problem with sending email by Gmail SMTP. Previously i had error that:

> Failure sending mail.

But now i changed some code and now i have his error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 64.233.167.109:465

I was so pissed off, that I started using wireshark to understand where the problem.

Here is what i found:

> > smtp.gmail.com Server:         53.90.35.60 Address:        53.90.35.60#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer: smtp.gmail.com  canonical name =
>   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com. Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.L.google.com
>   Address: 64.233.167.108 Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.L.google.com Address:
>   64.233.167.109

so as I understand there is response received from mail smtp server

Also we use proxy in our intranet, but I added proxy in my application, inside Web.config:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="true">
  <proxy proxyaddress="proxy_was_here" bypassonlocal="true"
  />
</defaultProxy>
```

and here is the part of new code:

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("email", "From Name");
                    var toAddress = new MailAddress("email", "To Name");
                    const string fromPassword = "pass";
                    const string subject = "Subject";
                    const string body = "Body";

                    var smtp = new SmtpClient
                    {
                        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                        Port = 465,
                        EnableSsl = true,
                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
                    };
                    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                    {
                        Subject = subject,
                        Body = body
                    })
                    {
                        smtp.Send(message);
                    }
```

If you have any questions, please look at my previous question or just write in the comments below.

Comment: Have you tried port 587? Also, email send functionality not working on both host server and local development machine?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Yes i tried all ports and it doesn't work on server neither

Answer (score 0):

Please try with port number 587 and EnableSSL = false

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
   Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
   Port = 587,
   EnableSsl = true,
   DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
   UseDefaultCredentials = false,
   Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
 };
```

also check with your credentials in https://www.smtper.net/

and also allow for less secure app from this link : https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

Comment: That really weird it doesn't work at all (Gmail and Yahoo)

Comment: please try this, 

     MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);
            mail.Subject = "Subject";
            mail.Body = "Body";//Console.ReadLine();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;

            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email-id", "password");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);

if you body not contains any HTML code then set isHtmlBody = false;

Comment: I turned on less secure app also in yahoo and it works on this website. But still doesn't work in my app.
SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Port: 587
Use SLL: True
Use Authentication: True